# Query to get tasks which end date are maximum 7 days from today

Tags: mysql

I have a tasks database which:

- id
- name
- start_date
- end_date

I need to retrieve tasks which end date are maximum today + 7 days. For example, if I have a task with 03/01/2018 end date, and today is 03/10/2018 it shouldn't appear. But if a task has 03/06/2018 end date, yes. And of course, all tasks which end date are superior to today must appear on the list.

I can achieve this through SQL query or should I do through programming language? Thanks.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why you shouldn't do it in the SQL query.

Comment: `WHERE end_date BETWEEN CURDATE() and DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)`

Comment: I don't understand your example. You said the end date has to be after today, but `3/6/2018` is not after `3/10/2018`.

Comment: @Barmar Maybe I explain bad. In that example, difference between 3/6 and 10/6 are not 7 days, so it should appear. So tasks should appear if end date are less than 7 days of difference from today. Sorry for my english and with my sql knowledge, im new on this.

Comment: Agreed, the query is the place to do this.

Comment: You should do it in SQL so that you don't have to retrieve ALL the task records from your table to process them in your application. That would be a poor use of resources and cause unnecessary latency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tasks`
WHERE end_date>= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY;
```

Comment: Thanks! I think its working now :) Didn't know how to get this without using programming language.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, name FROM tasks WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(end_date, CURDATE()))<=7
```